# How to determine whether the collections partition a set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For example

> For each of the collections $\{A_n\}_{n\in\Bbb R}$, determine whether the collections partition $\Bbb R^2$. Justify your answers, and sketch several of the sets $A_n$.
>
> $\quad$ (a) $A_n=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:y=2x+n\}$.

I know that for a collection to partition a certain set it must satisfy for example $A_1\bigcap A_2=\emptyset$ but and $\bigcup_{i=R}^\infty A_n=\Bbb R$ but Im having trouble wording this.

Please help.

this is my solution to the problem
Given (x,y)$\in$ $A_{y-2x}$ since y-2x=n is a line for every (x,y) then $\mathbb{R}$= $\bigcup_{i=R}^\infty$ $A_n$

Can anyone tell me if this would be a reasonable answer? thanks

Answer (score 2):

As you vary $n \in {\mathbb R}$, you are sweeping a line across the plane, with different $y$ intercepts. And clearly the $A_n$ are disjoint. So intuitively this does form a partition. To show this rigorously, let $x$ and $y$ be given and solve for $n$ so that $(x,y) \in A_n$ and show that the $n$ you get is unique.

Comment: I have my work as, Given (x,y)$\in$ $A_{y-2x}$ since y-2x=n is a line for every (x,y) then $\mathbb{R}$= $\bigcup_{i=R}^\infty$ $A_n$